# iOS: formSheet modalPresentationStyle view controller size shrinked

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I'm presenting a view controller with `modalPresentationStyle` set to `formSheet`, then I noticed the size of the view controller displayed isn't the same as how it's designed, it looks like iOS tries to shrink it to be smaller.

The doc says:

> In a horizontally regular environment, the view controller is sized so that its content area is smaller than the screen size and a dimming view is placed underneath the content.

It's not clear to me how the resizing is done (ie. "the view controller is sized so that..."), I have a button with left/right edge margin, which isn't preserved. Is this how iOS works? Do I need to set `preferredContentSize` if I want to force it to have certain size?

Thanks!

Comment: have you been able to figure it out?